# C++ - specialize class template's member function

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

I am looking for help with templates. I need to create function in template what will be reacting differently on a specific type.

It could looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
class SMTH
{
    void add() {...} // this will be used if specific function isn't implemented
    void add<int> {...} // and here is specific code for int
};
```

I also tried to use `typeid` and `swich` through types in a single function, but doesn't work for me.

Comment: you can specialize particular member of class template e.g : `template<> void SMTH<int>::add(){}` , but involves some caveats too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You really don't want to be doing this branching at runtime, with `typeid`.

We want this code:

```
int main()
{
    SMTH<int>().add();
    SMTH<char>().add();

    return 0;
}
```

To output:

```
int
not int
```

---

There are **lot of** ways I can think of to achieve this (all at compile time and half of them requires C++11):

1. **[Specialize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) the whole class** (if it has only this `add` function):

   ```
   template <typename T>
   struct SMTH
   {
       void add() { std::cout << "not int" << std::endl; }
   };

   template <>
   struct SMTH<int>
   {
       void add() { std::cout << "int" << std::endl; };
   };
   ```
2. **Specialize only the `add` member function** (recommended by @Angelus):

   ```
   template <typename T>
   struct SMTH
   {
       void add() { std::cout << "not int" << std::endl; }
   };

   template <> // must be an explicit (full) specialization though
   void SMTH<int>::add() { std::cout << "int" << std::endl; }
   ```

Note that if you instantiate `SMTH` with cv-qualified `int`, you'll get the `not int` output for above approaches.

3. **Use the [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) idiom.** There are few variants of it (default template argument, default function argument, function return type), and the last one is the one that fits here:

   ```
   template <typename T>
   struct SMTH
   {
       template <typename U = T>
       typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<U, int>::value>::type // return type
       add() { std::cout << "not int" << std::endl; }

       template <typename U = T>
       typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, int>::value>::type
       add() { std::cout << "int" << std::endl; }
   };
   ```

   The main benefit is that you can make the enabling condition complex, e.g. using `std::remove_cv` to choose the same overload regardless of cv-qualifiers.
4. **Tag dispatching** - chooses the `add_impl` overload based on if the instantiated tag inherits from `A` or `B`, in this case `std::false_type` or `std::true_type`. You still use template specialization or SFINAE, but this time it's done on a tag class:

   ```
   template <typename>
   struct is_int : std::false_type {};

   // template specialization again, you can use SFINAE, too!
   template <>
   struct is_int<int> : std::true_type {};

   template <typename T>
   struct SMTH
   {
       void add() { add_impl(is_int<T>()); }

   private:
       void add_impl(std::false_type)  { std::cout << "not int" << std::endl; }

       void add_impl(std::true_type)   { std::cout << "int" << std::endl; }
   };
   ```

   This can of course be done without defining the custom tag class, and the code in `add` will look like this:

   ```
   add_impl(std::is_same<T, int>());
   ```

---

I don't know if I mentioned them all, and I don't know why I attempted to, either. All you have to do now is to **choose the one that fits the use the best**.

Now, that I see, that you also wanted to check if a function exists. This is already long, and there's an [existing QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence) about that.